# Style inheritance based on different XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

How to specify BasedOn tag in a style to a style defined in some other file.

Example,

Dictionary1.xaml defines

```
   <Style x:Key="basicStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"></Setter>
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

In Dictionary2.xaml i need something like

```
    <Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="46"></Setter>
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easy way:

In `Dictionary2.xaml` define MergedDictionaries (right after the opening `ResourceDictionary` tag):

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Path/to/Dictionary1.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

And then

```
<Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}" >
    .....
</Style>
```

This will solve the issue, but as with all easy solutions there's a catch: each time you merge dictionaries you effectively create a copy of the merged dictionary. And it's recursive - if you have Dict3.xaml and Dict4.xaml that both load Dictionary2.xaml, you will have three instances of Dictionary1.xaml created. With a complex dependency structure you can get to a point that you have 19,000+ dictionary objects in memory at application start up and the memory footprint goes from 180MB to 1200MB (TrueStory™ :( ).

The solution is a [SharedResourceDictionary](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html). The implementation in the tutorial should be seen as a starting point and will probably need some level of tweaking - depending on use scenario. Google "wpf SharedResourceDictionary" for some gotchas and solutions.

Comment: I was looking for exactly same thing.
For the time being i will use the easy way, and also continue to explore SharedResourceDictionary.