# Import view from resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, resources

I have a resources file `Grids.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Label x:Key="SomeTestLabel">Hello There</Label>

    <Grid x:Key="HomeGrid">
        <Label Content="{StaticResource SomeTestLabel}"></Label>
    </Grid>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in my `Menus.xaml` file I have

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <TabItem x:Key="HomeTab" Header="Home">
        <Grid><!-- PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE --></Grid>
    </TabItem>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

- Is it possible to link `<Grid><!-- PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE --></Grid>` with `<Grid x:Key="HomeGrid">...</Grid>`?
- Is there a better View I could use?
- Is there a better way to do this?

The main reason I'm doing this is to refactor code out of one file (`MainWindow.xaml`) and into various other files, so that the main file and main resources file don't get cluttered with random pieces of code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import one ResourceDictionary into other, in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541424/how-to-import-one-resourcedictionary-into-other-in-wpf)

Comment: Don't do this. Control declarations don't belong inside a resource dictionary. A resource dictionary should be used for styles, brushes, themes, common images, converters, templates and maybe some other small stuff. But **never** *plain* control declarations. Those belong inside a `Window` or `UserControl`!

Comment: @Herdo thank you for pointing me towards `UserControl`s, they are *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Herdo hey I know this is years old but could you post the above comment as an answer? I want to mark this question as answered ^^

Comment: Check on that. Added some additional text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<ResourceDictionary />` is not ment to be a central place to declare controls. Things that are declared in one of those dictionaries is ment to be used *by* controls (e.g. styles, brushes, themes, common images, converters and templates).

However, control declarations (e.g. a `<Grid />`) is **always** an instance of that particular class that will be rendered by the WPF framework. A control can only exist at one place at a time, therefore, placing one inside a `ResourceDictionary` is not a good idea (it's not reusable anyway). Control declarations **always** belong inside the `UserControl`, `Window` or other hosting control where you want it to be displayed.